# Wortstellung bei zwei Modalverben im Nebensatz

Tags: word-order, modal-verb

Wie sieht die Wortstellung bei Nebensätzen mit zwei Modalverben aus? Wird das konjugierte Modalverb dem Doppelinfinitiv vorangestellt oder steht es eher am Ende des Satzes? Z. B.:

> Ich bin der Meinung, dass du diese Aufgabe **solltest** vollziehen können.

versus

> Ich bin der Meinung, dass du diese Aufgabe vollziehen können **solltest**.

Comment: Für mich klingt das erste Beispiel unnatürlich aber nicht ungrammatikalisch. Das zweite klingt m.E. viel besser.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Für mich klingt das erste besser, weil das, was man sollte, durch die Endstellung betont wird.

Comment: Für mich klingt es trotzdem unnatürlich.

Comment: Für mich klingt die zweite Variante sehr umständlich, die erste hingegen deutlich eleganter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Es ist tatsächlich so, dass das zweite Beispiel richtig ist, obwohl der Satz sich schon von einer Doppelinfinitivform im Nebensatz handelt.

Das ist so, weil das konjugierte Verb ein Modalverb ist. Wäre das konjugierte Verb eine Form von "haben" oder "werden", wäre das erste Beispiel richtig. Es kann aber kein konjugiertes Modalverb in den drittletzten Platz eines Nebensatzes kommen.

Weitere Beispiele:
"Er meinte, dass er das Auto erst letzte Woche *hätte* reparieren lassen können".

Das konjugierte Hilfsverb kommt vor die anderen Verben.

"Er meinte, dass er das Auto erst nächste Woche reparieren lassen *könne*".

Das konjugierte Modalverb kommt ans Ende.

"Sie fragt, ob du dir schon lange die Haare *hast* schneiden lassen wollen".

"Sie fragt, ob du dir schon lange die Haare schneiden lassen *wolltest*".

Comment: Dass im zweitletzen Beispiel eine infinite Form am Ende steht, dürte am Ersatzinfinitiv liegen. Beispiel bei Kurt Tucholsky: "Wenn ihr kein Recht über den Völkern anerkennt, (...) dann dürft ihr euch nicht wundern, wenn im Fall der Niederlage die Gegenseite über euch herfällt, wie ihr über sie *habt herfallen wollen*."

Answer (score 1):

Das Verb, das in einem Nebensatz am Ende steht, ist immer dasselbe, das in einem Hauptsatz an Position 2 steht. Welches das ist, kannst du also leicht rausfinden, indem du aus dem Nebensatz einen Hauptsatz machst. Dazu entfernst du die Subjunktion *dass* und alles außerhalb des Nebensatzes und ziehst das Verb, das an der letzten Stelle steht, an Position 2:

1. > Du **können** diese Aufgabe solltest vollziehen.
2. > Du **solltest** diese Aufgabe vollziehen können.

Jetzt sieht man sofort, dass Nr. 1 falsch ist, und dass nur Nr. 2 richtig ist. Auch der Grund leuchtet jetzt ein:

Das Verb, dass im Hauptsatz an Position 2 und im Nebensatz am Ende steht, muss das finite Verb sein. Das ist jenes Verb, das konjugiert wird, um mit dem Subjekt in Person und Numerus übereinzustimmen. Dasselbe Verb wird auch nach der grammatischen Zeit konjugiert. Alle anderen Verben kommen nämlich als Infinitiv, also ungebeugt vor. Die Verben *»vollziehen«* und *»können«* kann man in genau dieser Form im Wörterbuch finden. Anstelle von *»solltest«* müsste man aber in einem Wörterbuch nach einer anderen Form, nämlich nach *»sollen«* suchen. *»Solltest«* ist also eine finite Form, und daher muss dieses Verb im Hauptsatz an Position 2 und im Nebensatz am Ende stehen.

Comment: Das stimmt so nicht. Wenn mehrere Verbformen vorliegen – und das ist hier der Fall –, dann gibt es Ausnahmen. http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Wortstellung/Praedikat/index.html#Anchor-Ausnahme-35882

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich canoonet ist umgezogen, der folgende Link führt zum gleichen Artikel: http://www.canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Wortstellung/Praedikat/index.html#Anchor-Ausnahme-35882

Comment: @Adarain, danke.

Comment: Ein weiterer Link, da keiner von beiden zu funktionieren scheint: https://deutschegrammatik20.de/spezielle-verben/modalverben/wortposition-modalverbs/